# CSS Grid Navbar! How to align 2 divs near the middle and have 1 column the far left&right that span out on website stretch?

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigationbar

I'm pretty new to web development, but I'm having a lot of fun. I'm just struggling to figure out how I should do this efficiently. I'm trying to make a responsive navbar using CSS grid, though I haven't really gotten to the responsive bit yet. I've got 2 Divs at the moment, ***navbar*** (my navigation links) and ***settings*** (not entirely sure of what I'm doing with this yet, will include options like theme choices), I need these 2 divs to be centred and have a column on the far left & right that spans out when the window has been stretched far enough.

If possible, I'd also like a bit of help with styling my navigation links, I'm struggling to get rid of the underline even though I added **text-decoration: none;**. This is also my first time on StackOverflow, so please tell me if I'm doing something wrong here.

## HTML

```
<head>
    <title>EminaReads</title>
    <link id="theme" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body onload="CheckTheme()">
    <div hidden id="loading-wrapper">
        <header>

            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a class="active" href="#">Homepage</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Follow</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Info</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

            <div class="settings">
                <select id="theme-select">
                    <option hidden>Select Theme</option>
                    <option onclick="SwapTheme('./styles/Dark.css')" value="Dark">
                        Dark
                    </option>
                    <option onclick="SwapTheme('./styles/Light.css')" value="Light">
                        Light
                    </option>
                </select>
            </div>

        </header>
        <main>
            <div class="blog">
                <h2>Blog update1</h2>
                <h2>Blog update2</h2>
            </div>
            <aside>
                <p>Discord Link</p>
                <p>Music Player</p>
            </aside>
        </main>
        <footer>
            <p>Testing Footer</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
    <p id="js-alert">JAVASCRIPT</p>
</body>
</html>
```

## CSS

```
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: rgb(119, 119, 119);
}

/* Navigation System */
header {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0px;

    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;

    background-color: rgb(59, 59, 59);
    box-shadow: 0 4px 2px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

nav {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 4;
}

nav li {
    display: inline;
}

nav li a.active {
    background-color: #4caf50;
}
nav li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #111;
}

/* Settings */
.settings {
    grid-area: 1 / 4 / 2 / 6;
}

/* Content */
main {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 1fr);
}
.blog {
    grid-area: 2 / 2 / 8 / 7;
}
aside {
    grid-area: 2 / 7 / 8 / 9;
}
footer {
    margin-top: 1000px;
    background-color: grey;
}
```

## Javascript

```
function CheckTheme() {
    if (localStorage.savedtheme !== null) {
        document
            .getElementById("theme")
            .setAttribute("href", localStorage.savedtheme);
        console.log("if");
    } else {
        document.getElementById("theme").setAttribute("href", "./styles/Dark.css");
        console.log("else");
    }
    console.log("other");
    document.getElementById("loading-wrapper").removeAttribute("hidden");
    document.getElementById("js-alert").style.display = "none";
}

function SwapTheme(style) {
    document.getElementById("theme").setAttribute("href", style);
    localStorage.setItem("savedtheme", style);
}
```

See the Pen 
  [EminaReads](https://codepen.io/SakuraYagami/pen/LYVaRvO) by SakuraYagami ([@SakuraYagami](https://codepen.io/SakuraYagami))
  on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS for text-decoration should read:

```
nav li a {
  text-decoration: unset;
}
```

There's lots of different ways to achieve what you're looking for in terms of spacing the navbar, so what you end up using will depend on how you want the child elements to behave. If I've understood your requirements correctly, one simple way might be:

```
header {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr minmax(100px, 200px) minmax(100px, 200px) 1fr;
}

nav {
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3;
}

.settings {
  grid-area: 1 / 3 / 2 / 4;
}
```

I removed the extra column to simplify things. `minmax` means quite simply that the elements in those cells will shrink down to the minimum size, and grow up to the maxiumum size. So in this example while the page is less than 400px wide, they will take up the whole screen, after which the sidebars will enter and fill up the rest of the screen equally.

Answer (score -1):

> I need these 2 divs to be centred and have a column on the far left & right that spans out when the window has been stretched far enough.

To do this, you'll have to add 2 more elements and then give them some dimensions using grid-area. Bear in mind grid can only be used with the direct children of the element where display: grid is declared.

As far as the removing the underline, the CSS is correct, just make sure you're specific enough so you're selecting exactly the right element, using something like:

```
    nav ul li a {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The CSS is not correct and this is just not very good advice unfortunately.